# Vimrc conflict causes junk on load

Tags: vim

I'm getting some junk in my command bar when I load vim.  Specifically, `:95;c` appears, and I have to escape out.  This happens in Vim 7.2 (the one that comes with OS X), but not in MacVim, which uses 7.3.  I've narrowed it down to these two lines in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap <esc> :noh<cr>
```

If both lines are present, the junk shows up (with all plugins, colorschemes, and other vimrc lines, etc removed).  If either is disabled, it goes away.  I'm hella confused, since despite being a bit of a vimrc newb, I *think* I understand these lines.  I have no idea why they would conflict.

Comment: The Vim that ships with the systems before Lion is quite buggy. Since your vimrc is not available I can only suggest that you use MacVim from the terminal as replacement of the system vim. See  :h mvim  to see how you can make symlink name 'vim'

Comment: I just clarified my question a bit- there are no other lines in the vimrc.  I just ssh'd into a random host I have acces to with no vim config set up at all, added these two lines, and got the same result.  Vim 7.0 there.  The ultimate goal here is to be able to use my vimrc on remote systems without it breaking, so just using mvim all the time doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting. Happens to me too, Lion/vim 7.3

Comment: Mapping <esc> can be problematic. Here is an alternative mapping `:nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :noh<CR><C-l>`. I've seen people coming to the #vim irc channel having problems when ; is remapped.

Comment: Agreed with @El-Isra. Here's another alternative. Using the enter key. `nnoremap <silent> <CR> :noh<CR>`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid mapping `<Esc>`, especially in console Vim. This special key is used in the ANSI escape sequences used for terminal control and coloring.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was caused by a comment in the `.vimrc`, like this:

```
set background=light"can be light or dark
```

changed to add a space:

```
set background=light "can be light or dark
```

hope this helps someone.